# Update NSUserDefaults Nested Dictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a plist of level settings

defaultPrefs.plist

```
Root     Dictionary
Level1   Dictionary
 time     Number     0
 pushes   Number     0
 moves    Number     0
 unlocked Boolean    YES
Level2   Dictionary
 time     Number     0
 pushes   Number     0
 moves    Number     0
 unlocked Boolean    NO
```

etc

I'm registering them in the AppDelegate

```
let plist: String? = "defaultPrefs"

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(plist, ofType: "plist")!
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String: AnyObject]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(dict)
}
```

I'd like to update these

```
 func writeToPlist() {
      let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
      let level1Dict:AnyObject = defaults.objectForKey("Level1")!
      //let level1Dict:AnyObject = defaults.dictionaryForKey("Level1")!
      level1Dict.setValue(1, forKey: "moves")          
      //level1Dict.setInteger(1, forKey: "moves")
 }
```

Error:

> mutating method sent to immutable object

---

I'll pass in variables to choose the Dict Level and the Key etc once it's working

---

**Update**

```
let level1Dict:AnyObject = defaults.objectForKey("Level1")!.mutableCopy()

level1Dict.setValue(1, forKey: "moves")
defaults.setObject(level1Dict, forKey: "Level1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary returned from user defaults is immutable, so you need to make a mutable copy before you can edit it:

```
let level1Dict:AnyObject = defaults.objectForKey("Level1")!.mutableCopy()
```

Note also that editing the dictionary won't automatically update user defaults and you need to set the new dictionary for the key (to replace the full dictionary of old settings).

Comment: Thanks, could have sworn I'd tried that, but it's working now :)

defaults.setObject(level1Dict, forKey: "Level1")
I've updated the question with that too